# Change color of label when form option is selected

Tags: jquery

I know the 'easy' way to do this but I'm working with a form widget from a real estate agency, since I do not have API access I'm having to try and do some jQuery 'magic' to bring some UX functionality to life.

The widget contains labels along with check boxes, radio buttons, select and input fields.

The only thing that ties these together is they are all self contained within a div that has a class of 'frmRow' within this containing div there is another div with a class of 'frmLabel' that contains the label. There is also a second div with a class of 'frmInput'. I basically need to identify that an option has been selected in this '.frmRow' so change the color of the nested '.frmLabel' div.

I can pull it off using strict class names but I need it to be a little more generic so it applies to all form options within me having to create gigantic if/else block of code.

Any ideas would be much appreciated

Here is a snippet of the html if it will help

```
<form id="form">

<div class="frmRow">

    <div class="frmLabel">Label</div>

   <div class="frmInput">Radio, Select, Checkbox or Text Input </div>

</div>

</form>
```

Thanks Tim,

It's working (kind of) but it's changing the color of the label for all elements. I'm new to jQuery so it's possible I'm not understanding how parent() works. I'd think that the parent of .frmInput would be .frmRow but it looks like it considers the containing div for the form the parent. Is there anyway I can specify what parent I'm looking for? Here is the code.

```
$('#homefinderform').click(function() {

    if($('.frmInput input').is(':checked')) { 

            $(this).parent().addClass('frmLabelChecked');

    }

});
```

Comment: Posting your code of it working with strict class names would be helpful, especially as a jsfiddle or jsbin working example.

Comment: Will do it when I get home, sorry didn't cross my mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of sloppy with the 2 `.parent()`s, but if you can't modify the HTML itself then you gotta take what you can get. This should give you a head-start on how to make this work.

http://jsfiddle.net/4GEXq/

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the help. Going to edit my original post and let you know what's happening.

Comment: Can we see this live somewhere so I can understand what's happening? Or post the relevant parts on a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sure, give me a moment to upload. Thanks again, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Pretty much, except I'm looking for the color of the label text to change not the row itself. So what I'm trying to do is add a class (or in your case css) to the parent of the input which should be '.frmRow' but for some reason it's applying it to the containing div for the form? Does this make sense? I'd hate to take up too much of your time I can probably try to make it work from here (hopefully).

Comment: Also, another thing if I try to specify the parent - ie parent('.frmRow') it stops working completely for some reason.

Comment: Ok, I think this is it. Like I said, it's messy, but without access to the HTML your hands are kind of tied. http://jsfiddle.net/4GEXq/4/

Comment: Hmm, oddly enough it doesn't work when applied to the widget. I'll tinker it with it and see if I can get it working. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: The HTML is a bit more complicated than it seemed. Lots of parents, but this seems to work... http://jsfiddle.net/4GEXq/5/

Comment: Yeah, I got it going. I'll have to be more specific though. It's changing the color of every label but I would assume it's due to the default values of the form fields. I guess that's another issue I'll have to work out. You got me on the right path though, much appreciated.